# positioning different component in java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, layout-manager

im trying to design java GUI frame which contains labels, textfields,  radio buttons and button..

i want to position each component in specific place  tried setBounds() but it didn't work..

also im trying to change background color of the frame using getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white) and setBackground(Color.white) but didnt work too.

how to do it ?

this is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class test extends JFrame{ 

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame(); 
     guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     guiFrame.setTitle("WHO IS THE WINNER"); 
     guiFrame.setSize(700,500);
     guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 


     final JPanel first = new JPanel();
     JLabel un = new JLabel("UserName:");
     JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
     JLabel sn = new JLabel("Server Name:");
     JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(20);
     un.setLabelFor(textField);
     sn.setLabelFor(textField2);
     first.add(un);
     first.add(textField); 
     first.add(sn); 
     first.add(textField2); 



     final JPanel second = new JPanel(); 
     JLabel level = new JLabel("Level:");
     JLabel score = new JLabel("Score:");
     JLabel question = new JLabel("Question:");
     CheckboxGroup  radioGroup = new CheckboxGroup(); 
     Checkbox radio1 = new Checkbox("True", radioGroup,false); 
     Checkbox radio2 = new Checkbox("False", radioGroup,true);
     second.add(score); 
     second.add(level); 
     second.add(question); 
     second.add(radio1);
     second.add(radio2);

     JButton next = new JButton( "Next");
     next.addActionListener(
           new ActionListener() { 
              @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                 first.setVisible(false); 
              } }); 

     guiFrame.add(first, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     guiFrame.add(second, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     guiFrame.add(next,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
     guiFrame.setVisible(true);

  } 
}
```

for the positioning for example i want the first label and text field under them the other label and text field not beside them.. same for other labels and radio buttons i don't want  them it be beside each other i want o give them a specific position to be in..

can someone please help ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you working on Eclipse? Have you tried it from the tab design?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just for Eclipse IDE.

An easy way to place all the widgets is doing it from the **Design** tab, placed at the bottom-left side of the window. Just change from Source perspective to Design perspective. It will open a simple panel with everything you need. Just drag the different widgets and place them in their position.

To change the background of the frame, do it from the properties of the frame in the Design tab or add the following code to the constructor of the panel:

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```